# How to write this code below in PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have an old mysql code which I want to convert into PHP data object but I cant find on the web how this can be done, any help?

```
    $num = mysql_num_rows($result = mysql_query($query));

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {

...
}
```

$query is a SELECT statement.

UPDATE:

My code is only showing the message "could not find driver" and notihng else, it isn't showing form code or anything like that. What am i doing wrong in my PDO? I know database, hostname, username and password are correct so it should be able to show form and then let me connect to DB.

```
<?php

session_start(); 

$hostname = 'localhost';
$username="xxx";
$password="xxx";
$database="mobile_app";

try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database", $username, $password);


?>

,,, //Form Code is in here

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$query = "
SELECT * FROM Teacher t  
WHERE 
(t.TeacherUsername = '".mysql_real_escape_string($teacherusername)."')
AND
(t.TeacherPassword = '".mysql_real_escape_string($teacherpassword)."')
";

$loged = false;

foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row)
  {

,,,, //results for each row



  }

 $dbh = null;

}

    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

// PDOStatement is traversable, so you could use foreach.
foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row) {
  //...
}
```

Comment: Hi, just need to ask 1 little question, is `$dbh = null;` at bottom of script equivalent to mysql_close()?

Comment: @user1438647: There's not usually much point in setting anything to `null` before the bottom of a script. You just don't have to do anything.

Comment: @user1438647 The connection will be released after the php script exit, usually you don't need to do that.

Comment: @xdazz I am having problem connecting to the database I think as that in my application it is just displaying message "could not find driver" and it doesn't show anything else. Am I doing something wrong in my code? I have updated question for you to see

Comment: @user1438647 So that is because you don't have the `pdo-mysql` installed.

Comment: Oh, where do I install it from and does it work for all php versions?

Comment: I did not install php, The server I am using (university server) contains it's own version of php but it is an older version of php, I am checking version of php now

Comment: @user1438647 If it's not your server, you have no way to install it. Contact to the server admin.

Answer (score 3):

```
$result = $link->query($query); # Replace $link with your database handle
$rows = $link->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
$num = count($rows);

foreach($rows as $row) {
    # ...
}
```

…is the direct equivalent. Of course, you probably won't need `PDO::FETCH_BOTH` (I recommend `PDO::FETCH_OBJ` for the same sort of functionality in a cleaner package), and you'll probably want to take advantage of parametrized queries, in which case you'd call `prepare` instead of `query`, then bind the parameters, then call `execute()` to fetch the results.

You may find [the reference for `PDOStatement`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php) helpful.

EDIT: As commenters point out, `rowCount()` isn't that great, even if it is the most direct equivalent. I've updated it with something better.

Comment: It might be worth noting that in some cases `PDOStatement::rowCount()` doesn't return the right value. In such condition, it is needed to either do `SELECT COUNT(*)` or `count(PDOStatement::fetchAll())`. Albeit, I somewhat doubt that the OP need to do so.

Comment: @KemalFadillah: Which cases? (I hope the cases you mention aren't common, or else I have quite some modification to do!)

Comment: So you are saying it should be like this: `$result = $dbh->prepare($query); 
$num = $result->rowCount();

while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
    # ...
}` $dbh is connection to db

Comment: @user1438647: You'll need a `$result->execute();` in there, but that's the idea. Of course, if there are no parameters to the query, by all means just use `query()`.

Comment: @minitech Don't worry, they're not so common. In fact, I've never encountered such problem with PHP & MySQL. But then again, I always use the latest version of those two. Anyway, here's some example: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php#88352 & http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php#80041. I think there are more then these two in the comments, but I'm getting lazy to search for the rest. :P

Comment: I wouldn't advice for rowCount. Even the documentation says the same. You are advicing something which is unreliable (not saying it is wrong all the time) from the begining.